# I'm trying to print a calender, but I couldn't get my result aligned

Tags: c, calendar

This is what I've done so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int days, start, i, j;

printf("Enter number of days in month: ");
scanf("%d", &days);

printf("Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 2=Mon, ......, 7=Sat): ");
scanf("%d", &start);

printf("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");

for(i=0; i<(start-1); i++)
    printf("    ");

for(j=1; j<=days; j++){
    printf("%3d", j);

    if((j+i)%7==0)
        printf("\n");}

 printf("\n\n");

 return 0;

}
```

This is my result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc15H.png)

Can anybody tell me where's wrong? I'm new to programming, so I'll appreciate if you can write the answers in a simpler way. Thank you so much!

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: BTW, you need to add a `\n` after the format string in `printf("Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 2=Mon, ......, 7=Sat): ");`

Comment: Isn't it will jump directly to the new line if I use the scanf? The problem is I couldn't get my result aligned...

Comment: Sidenote: You must always check to return value of `scanf` family functions. If they don't return `1`, you'll get *undefined behaviour* (= very bad), because `days` and `start` are not initialized.

Comment: Wao, I didn't know that before! Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: please consistently indent the code (suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level (never use tabs) )  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when getting information from the user, always validate that information.  With the posted code, the user could enter 900 or -10 for the number of days in the month.   Similar with which day of the week that the 1st lies upon

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   Where you should consider the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    printf("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");
```

use

```
    printf("\n Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");    // New line and an extra space
```

then instead of

```
    printf("    ");
```

use

```
    printf("     ");                               // 5 spaces instead of 4
```

and instead of

```
    printf("%3d", j);
```

use

```
    printf("%4d", j);                              // 4 positions (1 for an extra space)
```

Comment: I did as you told, and it's work!!! Thank you so muchhhh!!!*★,°*:.☆\(￣▽￣)/$:*.°★*

Answer (score 0):

Nearly correct. A correct version is:

```
int main(void)
{
    int days=30, start=3, i, j;

    printf("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n");

    for(i=0; i<(start-1); i++)
        printf("    ");

    for(j=1; j<=days; j++){
        //i++;
        printf("%3d ", j);

        if((j+i)%7==0)
            printf("\n");
    }
     printf("\n\n");
     return 0;
}
```

You don't need to increment `i` in the loop and you had to allign the output.

Output:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
          1   2   3   4   5 
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
 13  14  15  16  17  18  19 
 20  21  22  23  24  25  26 
 27  28  29  30
```

Answer (score 0):

each day number needs to be printed in the same width (4 columns) so the print statement should look something like

```
printf("%4.4d", j);
```

which will have all the numbers 1 space to the right.

This could be corrected in two ways

1) insert a space at the beginning of the literal that prints out the column headers (my preference)

or

2) check to see if it is the first entry in a line and use a print statement similar to, only for that first entry:

```
printf("%3,3d", j);
```